# Fast Import to SQL Through VB.net(2005)

Tags: vb.net

I have text file which contain the 15000000 Rows with the Comma delimiters..i want to import that file to SQL Table Through VB.net(2005) With 1000 Rows per seconds
    Is that Possible through VB.net

Please help me...
Thanx in Advance

Comment: Do you care about the speed of the process because it is not a one-time event? Will you have to repeat this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the [sqlbulkcopy class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx).

Comment: can we map Text file Column with SQL table Column  using SQLBULK Copy CLASS.

Comment: you need to do some work implementing the source as an IDataReader.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you tell us what kind of SQL table is that.

In SQL Server you use [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx). If you must use Vb.Net code, the functionality is exposed in .Net via the [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class. A more sensible approach is to use [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx).